# Infinitely repeating print statement

Tags: math, printing, repeat, infinite

I'm currently working on a project where the user is required to enter a number and the program will determine whether or not the number is prime. The problem here is that the print statement repeats itself once executed and the only way to stop it is to kill the program as it's working.

Here's the code for the program:

```
print("Here, you will be asked to enter a number and the program will 
       determine whether said number is prime. ")

print ("For the sake of simplicity, we'll only be using numbers that are 
        below 100. ")

Number = int (input("Please enter a number and we will determine if the 
number you entered if prime. "))

for Number in range (1,98):
    for y in range (1,98):
        if Number %y!=0:
            print ("This number is, in fact, a prime number. ")
        else:
            if Number %y==0:
                print ("This number is not prime.")
```

Comment: Please update your question with valid formatting and mention the language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

For a number to be prime, it should be divisible only by itself and 1. 
So, all you need to check is for numbers between [2,n), if it is divisible by any number, then it is not a prime and you need to break the for loop.

If the for loop is broken when you reach the end, then that means no number between [2,n) is a factor of that number, hence the number is prime. We check if the loop is broken naturally or not using isPrime boolean flag

PS. The program might not compile as I did not run it, but the logic is right

```
print ("Here, you will be asked to enter a number and the program will determine whether said number is prime. ") 
print ("For the sake of simplicity, we'll only be using numbers that are below 100. ")
isPrime = True
Number = int (input("Please enter a number and we will determine if the number you entered if prime. "))

for y in range (2,Number): 
    if Number%y==0 and Number!=y: 
       isPrime = False
       print ("This number is not prime.")
       break
if isPrime:
       print "Number is prime"
```